# Is it safe to cache the POSITION object of a CAtlList object?

Tags: c++, atl

I have a `CAtlList` structure. For efficient lookups in certain cases, I am saving the `POSITION` object of `CAtlList` in a `CAtlMap<String, POSITION>` structure. Is it guaranteed that the `POSITION` object will not change underneath due to various operations on the `CAtlList` structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  A `CAtlList` is a linked list and adding or removing elements from it does not affect other elements in the list.

The `POSITION` is effectively the address of an element in the list, and the address of an element will not change once it is inserted (until it is removed, of course, at which point the object ceases to exist).